# MongoDB Sharding Key with DBRef field?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, data-collection

I have a collection that contains DBRefs to a root document. I have tens of thousands documents that link to a single root document in my Data collection. 
That's why I chose to not nest the data of the root document.

```
Data Collection:
    _id : Auto-Created ID
    ts : TimeStamp 
    field_1 : Whatever
    ...
    field_n : Whatever 
    root : DBRef

"Root" Document Collection:
    _id: Filename (unique)
    field_1 : Whatever
    ...
    field_n : Whatever
```

I think the best way to shard my collection is using the fields `ts` and `root._id` as a compound key.

Is that possible? If not, what's the best solution? Simply copy the `root._id` field into a normal field in the Data collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, here's what I found out:

Apparently, this is not possible because all DBRefs have to be retrieved on the client side in a subsequent query.

I have ingested a new field `sh_key` that gets created on-the-fly while importing the data on the application side. The new field will hold the value of the "compound sharding key".

The value is a concatenation of the `root._id` value as well as the hour of the `ts` in the fashion of `{root._id}:{hour of ts}`.